# How to check UDF exists in cosmos DB with sdk v3?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

In sdk v2, I used the code below to check if udf exists or not

```
UserDefinedFunction udf = _client.CreateUserDefinedFunctionQuery(collectionSelfLink).Where(p => p.Id == udfId).AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();
        if (udf != null)
        {
            //
        }
```

But in v3  I have not found a function equivalent of `CreateUserDefinedFunctionQuery`.
How should I do to know if the UDF already exists?

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like the following:

```
    static async Task<bool> CheckIfUdfExists(string udfId)
    {
        var client = new CosmosClient("connection-string");
        var db = client.GetDatabase("database-id");
        var container = db.GetContainer("container-id");
        QueryDefinition queryDefinition = new QueryDefinition("SELECT * FROM u where u.id = @testId")
            .WithParameter("@testId", udfId);
        bool udfExists = false;
        using (FeedIterator<UserDefinedFunctionProperties> feedIterator = container.Scripts.GetUserDefinedFunctionQueryIterator<UserDefinedFunctionProperties>(queryDefinition))
        {
            while (feedIterator.HasMoreResults)
            {
                foreach (var properties in await feedIterator.ReadNextAsync())
                {
                    udfExists = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return udfExists;
    }
```

Comment: I would actually recommend that you use answer from @SteveZhao. It is much better IMO. That should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Gaurav's answer is correct, you can also use `ReadUserDefinedFunctionAsync` function to check whether UDF exists. This function will return 404 StatusCode when it doesn't exist.

Code:

```
bool udfExists;
try
{
    UserDefinedFunctionResponse udfResponse = await cosmosScripts.ReadUserDefinedFunctionAsync(udfId);
    udfExists = true;
 }
 catch (CosmosException e)
 {
     if (e.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
     {
         udfExists = false;
         //.................
     }
     else
     {
         throw;
     }
 }
```

SDK Version: [Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos 3.17.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos/)

Comment: @GauravMantri It can work fine in v3.17.0. I give the wrong API link. Sorry for that.

Comment: @SteveZhao...Thanks. For some reason I completely missed that. Your answer is definitely better than mine.

Comment: cosmosScripts is available on the Container.Scripts prop